# How to remove the modal and backdrop without hurting second display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal wrote by

```
$(document).on('click', '.generate-modal-button', App.proposals.elementClickHandler);
function elementClickHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#state-modal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }, 'show');
}
```

This modal contains textarea and a submit button. In my other JS file, there's a function to get the input from the textarea of the modal, and an ajax request to update this input will be sent after submit button clicked.

The problem is I want to close this modal and remove the backdrop after the submit button clicked, I used

```
$('#state-modal').removeAttr('style');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

to remove it and it works fine. However, the modal not shows up when I click the `generate-modal-button` again, it seems like the `$('#state-modal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }, 'show');` not working after I remove all these elements, class and attribute. I wonder how can I remove this modal safely without hurting its next appearance?

Comment: To the one who gave a comment about '$('body')' thing and deleted: Thank you, I changed it to '$(document.body)' but it's still can't be displayed in second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close a Bootstrap modal using Javascript/jQuery, use `$('#modal').modal('hide');`

See the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#modalhide